# Could the crowd have provided the extra bread and fish in the account of Jesus feeding the thousands?

Tags: jesus, gospels, miracle

In all of the feeding miracles (Matthew 14:13-21,  Matthew 15:32-16:10, Mark 6:31-44, Mark 8:1-9, Luke 9:10-17 and John 6:5-15) would it have been possible that the extra bread and fish did not get miraculously created?  Instead since the crowd was all sitting and saw Jesus break the bread and fish that they also decided to break up their own bread and fish that they might have had with them to have fed everyone there?

Comment: Welcome and thanks for stopping by the Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange!  When you have a minute, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on  how this site is [a little different](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives#803) than most other sites. *This is not a comment on the quality of your question, but rather a standard welcome message.*

Comment: It would seem this question calls for speculation, even after the edit. I really don't know how an objective answer can be given, because there is no specification stated in scripture about how the bread and fish multiplied, outside of a supernatural (divine) miracle.

Comment: @seedy3 I'd be fine seeing it closed as opinion-based, but that is up to the community to decide.

Comment: @dan I understand, that was must my observation of the topic.

Comment: @seedy3 Seems like an OK question to me.  As Dick's answer shows, it is possible to draw a conclusion (even if not a certain one) from the text itself.

Comment: @Thaddeus it is possible to draw a conclusion about the gospel author's intent and belief when writing. It is not possible To verify the historicity of the accounts. Dick's answer is good because it focuses on the former, while this questions asks for speculation on the latter. Evidence that it is focused on the historical event itself and not a specific text is the fact that all parallel accounts are given. Each gospel author may have had his own intent behind recording this account. Instead of asking about a specific text, the OP is asking about the event itself.

Comment: Even so, I won't unilaterally close this if the community disagrees.

Comment: Are you asking for scriptural, logical or mythological evidence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, unless (in the first feast, feeding the five thousand) the disciples made a foolish assumption:

> Mark 6:36: Send them away, that they may go into the country round about, and into the villages, and buy themselves bread: *for they have nothing to eat*.

From that verse, we ought to assume the crowd really did have nothing to eat. Even less likely would be that Jesus made the same false assumption in the second feast (feeding the four thousand):

> Mark 8:2-3: I have compassion on the multitude, because they have now been with me three days, and have nothing to eat: And if I send them away fasting to their own houses, they will faint by the way: for divers of them came from far.

The options are then limited: either the bread and fish were created miraculously, or the gospel author was misinformed about these events. The texts of the three synoptic gospels often agree very closely in wording and order, both in quotations and in narration. [Most scholars ascribe this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synoptic_Gospels#The_synoptic_problem) to documentary dependence meaning that, in the absence of a miracle, only one evangelist (presumably the author of *Mark*) need have been misinformed.